# Can "être sur" mean "to be about" ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Can "être sur" be used as "to be about"? Examples:

- Ce livre est sur la naissance du capitalisme.
- C'est sur le vol de la plus grande banque du pays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*être sur* for *be about* is fine.  It's a bit informal, though.  As LPH rightly suggests, *c'est un livre sur* is more common than *ce livre est sur*.  Another way, more formal, that works well and that could be used in, say, a paper is :

- Ce livre a pour objet la naissance du capitalisme.

But there are many other ways to express the same idea.

Comment: et  « avoir pour sujet »,  « parler de », « traiter de »...

Comment: et "porter sur"

Comment: It seems to me that "C'est un livre sur" / "C'est sur" is much more usual than "Ce livre est sur" ? If that is true, it'd be nice to include it in the answer.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Detto, fatto!

Comment: @petitrien Ecco, aussitôt dit, aussitôt fait !

Answer (score 2):

"Ce livre est sur X" is little used; much prefered is "C'est un livre sur X" (voir [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ce+livre+est+sur%2Cc%27est+un+livre+sur&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cce%20livre%20est%20sur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cc%27est%20un%20livre%20sur%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cce%20livre%20est%20sur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cc'est%20un%20livre%20sur%3B%2Cc0)).

"C'est sur X" is comonly used ([ngram1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=c%27est+sur+la+guerre+&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cc%27est%20sur%20la%20guerre%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cc'est%20sur%20la%20guerre%3B%2Cc0),[ngram2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=c%27est+sur+l%27amour&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cc%27est%20sur%20l%27%20amour%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cc'est%20sur%20l'%20amour%3B%2Cc0),  [ngram3](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=c%27est+sur+la+libert%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cc%27est%20sur%20la%20libert%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cc'est%20sur%20la%20libert%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0)).

- c'est sur la guerre
- c'est sur l'amour
- c'est sur la liberté